# Will jQuery ajax cache even if php headers are issued to the contrary?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, caching

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ states that cache's default value is `true`, and if set to `false`, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser.

if `cache` is set to `true` but the server returns some headers stating not to cache, will the client still attempt to use cached results?  Are there some browsers which experiences different behavior in this regard?

```
<?php

header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are concerned with caching what `cache:true` does is append a timestamp to url.

This makes it a unique url therefore it is virtually impossible for browser to cache since browser will have no reference to that url

In regards to whether the client will attempt to cache the results if the server issues headers not to do so, "realistically it should work" and the client will not cache the results.

Comment: Yes, I am aware how a timestamp is used to make each URL unique and thus never cached.  I am asking if `cache` is `true` thus the same URL will be used, will the results be cached if the server issues headers to do differently.

Comment: Not really sure so if it is a concern use the timestamp...unless you are asking with regard to providing an api for others to access. Can also add an expires header that is in the past too

Comment: Not really sure either, but would like to know for sure.  I typically put the headers in the server response as it knows if something has changed, but if doing so doesn't have any effect on behavior, I should be doing differently.

Comment: I have tested it on several modern browsers, and the client will not cache the results.  Don't know for sure on older browsers, however...